# Ruby connect to mysql using login path

Tags: mysql, ruby

I'm trying to create a connection to mysql from ruby script using login path.
I've set the login path in the following way:

```
mysql_config_editor set --login-path=login-path --host=host-name --user=user --password
```

Now in my ruby script I have the following line:

```
require 'mysql2'
$mysql_connection = Mysql2::Client.new(:default_file => '~/.mylogin.cnf',:default_group => 'login-path')
```

And I get the following error:

> error: Found option without preceding group in config file:
>   /home/user/.mylogin.cnf at line: 3 Fatal error in defaults handling.
>   Program aborted

When I'm connecting like this, it succeed:

```
require 'mysql2'
$mysql_connection = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => 'host-name', :username => "user", :password => "password", :database => 'database_name')
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Run the "mysql_config_editor" and ruby script in the same system account?

Comment: @GreenBlade, I'm running from the same user.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with your 'default_group' setting.  I have standard mysql setup using a typical login-path of 'client', eg:

```
% mysql_config_editor print
[client]
password = *****
```

and the following connect works with no issue:

```
@client = Mysql2::Client.new(host: MySQL_Host, username: MySQL_User, default_group: 'client', database: MySQL_Database)
```

Comment: Alternatively, you may have a '#' in your password - that is known to be a problem...